# Show that $R(k,l) = R(l,k)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $R(k,l)$ denote the Ramsey number.We proved in class a theorem that says

$$R(k,l) \leq {k+l-2\choose{k-1}} $$

And supposedly we can use this to show that $R(k,l) = R(l,k)$ for all $k,l \in \mathbb{N}$. However I am not seeing it. I feel like I use should induction, but I'm not sure how. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don’t see any way to use the inequality to prove that $R(k,\ell)=R(\ell,k)$ for all $k,\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$, nor do I see any reason to try such a roundabout approach: it’s almost immediate from the definition that $R(k,\ell)=R(\ell,k)$, since it’s just a matter of reversing the colors.

Comment: Alright. I thought so. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$${k+l-2\choose{k-1}}=\frac{(k+l-2)!}{(k-1)!(k+l-2-(k-1))!}=\frac{(k+l-2)!}{(k+l-2-(l-1))!(l-1)!}={k+l-2\choose{l-1}}$$

Thus, $k$ and $l$ are interchangable.